# How to detect when $form_state data have expired (and gotten deleted)?

Tags: hooks, forms

***Problem:*** a user opens a multi-page form and fills out several sections – submitting each time – before returning hours later to finish the remaining parts, leaving their browser open (perhaps needing to look for additional documents or consult with a colleague). When they come back, they are still logged in, but the [hard-coded 6-hour limit](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/includes/form.inc#L559) on storage of their `$form_state` data has elapsed, and the values they submitted in the previous sections of the form will not load on their next navigation-action since they have been deleted.

***Background:*** for multi-page forms, Drupal stores working `$form_state` information in the `cache_form` table until the final submission-step is complete, but its `"expire"` column is set so that deletion occurs 6 hours after creation. Even if this value [is changed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/cache-form-drupal-change-expire-time/96746), sites featuring multi-page forms may still encounter the above situation, wherein an in-progress form is submitted after `$form_state` information has been discarded.

How can one detect when this circumstance arises (so the user can be informed of this or so that recovery-actions can be silently taken)?

***Note:*** Though you're welcome to post a Javascript answer if you have one, I won't assume Javascript is always available, and therefore do not consider answers which rely on Javascript to be robust.

Answer (score 0):

Although this arrangement is probably more complicated than it needs to be, here's how I was able to achieve it. I'd be happy to accept another answer if someone has a more elegant solution.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function my_module_form($form, $form_state) {

    if (isset($form_state['storage']['elements_to_append'])) {
    // If other functions want us to add elements to the form:
        $elements = $form_state['storage']['elements_to_append'];
        foreach( $elements as $key => $element ) {
            $form[$key] = $element;
        }
    }

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#submit' => array(
            'my_module_submit',
            'my_module_submit_safety',
            // ^ Depending on your requirements, you may wish to switch the
            // run-order of these two functions. Having my_module_submit_safety()
            // put first prevents subsequent actions in the case that $form_state
            // was lost since last navigation, but your users may lose more pages
            // of work before this check becomes effective; it's a tradeoff
            // either way unless you want to run the safety-check twice.
        ),
    );

    return $form;

} // my_module_form() OUT

/**
 * Implements hook_submit().
 */
function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $form_state['rebuild'] = true;

    $form_state['storage']['elements_to_append']['navigated'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => 1,
    );

} // my_module_submit() OUT

/**
 * Implements hook_submit().
 */
function my_module_submit_safety($form, &$form_state) {

    $form_state_cid = '';
    if (isset($form_state['input']['form_build_id'])) {
        $form_state_cid = 'form_state_' . $form_state['input']['form_build_id'];
        // ^ This is effectively the same way the CID is built in @see
        // form_set_cache()
    }

    $statement = db_select('cache_form','cf');
    $statement->fields( 'cf', array('expire') );
    $statement->condition('cid', $form_state_cid);

    $navigated = isset($form_state['input']['navigated']);

    if ( $statement->execute()->fetchAssoc() === FALSE && $navigated ) {
        throw new Exception("The state-information for this form has expired.");
        // ^ I just place an exception here because recovery-actions for this
        // case are going to be system-dependent. If you know what those are for
        // your situation, they'd go here instead of this `throw` statement.
    }

} // my_module_submit_safety() OUT
```

Above, we use `$form_state['input']` rather than `$form_state['values']` since the latter will ***not*** include the results of the hidden field sent from the client's stale page in the case that `$form_state` information has been deleted. The strange dance of appending elements from a `'#submit'` step is done so that we don't run aground of the fact that `my_module_form()` is actually invoked ***twice*** (once immediately before `'#submit'` functions are called, and once after, each time with different values).

***To test whether it works:***

1. Load the form.
2. Navigate once.
3. Do: `mysql -u <userName> -D <databaseName> [-p<password>] -e\
   "DELETE FROM <prefix>_cache_form";`.
4. Navigate again. You should see the message appear after this step.

---

**Note:** for security purposes, one might actually want to encrypt the hidden field's value (salting, timestamping, and including it no matter what), then reject the form outright if the value is found to be missing or adulterated in some way.